# cannot install python using brew

Tags: python, installation, homebrew

Trying to install python using the following command:

`brew install python`

But unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
>brew install python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-2.7.12_2.el_capitan.
Already downloaded: /Users/maguerra/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.12_2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-2.7.12_2.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg insta
Last 15 lines from /Users/maguerra/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/post_install.01.python:
copying setuptools/command/rotate.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/saveopts.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/sdist.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/setopt.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/test.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/upload.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/upload_docs.py -> build/lib/setuptools/command
creating build/lib/setuptools/extern
copying setuptools/extern/__init__.py -> build/lib/setuptools/extern
copying setuptools/script (dev).tmpl -> build/lib/setuptools
copying setuptools/script.tmpl -> build/lib/setuptools
running install_lib
copying build/lib/easy_install.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
copying build/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall python`

==> Caveats
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them 
  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and Python.md

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps python` to symlink these to /Applications.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2: 3,150 files, 42.5M
```

Has anyone seen this before, or now how to address this issue in order to complete the python installation process?

Answer (score 2):

The error message says you don’t have permission to write under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources`.

The following steps should work:

1. Remove your broken Python install:

   ```
   brew uninstall python
   ```
2. Ensure you own that directory:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ```
3. Retry:

   ```
   brew install python
   ```

Comment: I had to update my path to this: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /Users/YourUser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` for it to find it.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Python3 with Brew**
Enter brew command into terminal

```
brew install python3
```

Optional, PATH environment
Set up PATH environment variable, if you used HomeBrew to install Python3, then HomeBrew already added PATH.

Do not change PATH environment if you can launch python3 from terminal.

Add the following line to your ~/.profile file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Usually your Python installation directory looks like this, add it to your PATH

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
```